# How reconize a flex token with another token?

Tags: flex-lexer

I'm trying to reconize the next token with Flex

```
trasnicion \(simbolo\,simbolo\;simbolo\)
```

using the token `simbolo [a-zA-Z0-9]`  but when I execute my program doesn't work.

However, if I do `trasnicion \([a-zA-Z0-9]\,[a-zA-Z0-9]\;[a-zA-Z0-9]\)` works perfecly.

Can someone explain me why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A macro expansion in (f)lex is written `{simbolo}`. If you just write `simbolo`, that requires a match of the literal string "simbolo".

In this case, you might consider not using macros, since the standard character class `[[:alnum:]]` means exactly the same thing.